# Windows 7, Xubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 13.04 triple-double boot :)

Tags: 12.10, windows, 13.04, dual-boot

I currently have Windows 7 and Xubuntu 12.10 and that is working fine.
Now I want to make some free space out of Windows partition and install Ubuntu 13.04 on it.

So my question is: 
Would that be a problem (two versions of Ubuntu and Windows)? Would be some GRUB conflicts?

P.S. I know that I can test new Ubuntu using Live boot or via VirtualBox but 
I want to see how it works with property drivers.

Sorry for my poor English and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general this isn't a problem, but there are some things to keep in mind:

- If you are using a MBR partition table, and already have four primary partitions, you won't be able to create a new partition (except for partitions inside an extended partition).
- The system  from which you are installing your bootloader, will be first in the GRUB menu. Additionally you have to update the bootloader after every kernel update that happened in the system which isn't at the top of the boot menu. (You update your bootloader with `sudo update-grub` and you can reinstall it with `sudo  grub-install /dev/sdX` where X is the drive to install your bootloader to (in most cases it's an 'a'))

Answer (score 0):

Grub will be fine... In fact when you install Ubuntu it will overwrite your old grub with a new grub with the three options - Windows 7, Xubuntu, and Ubuntu...